# Realm .NET - Criar copia de objeto

Tags: c#, xamarin, realmdb

Pessoal estou com problema usando Realm, em .NET com Xamarin.

Eu posso normalmente adicionar, atualizar ou excluir objetos de um Realm. Mas como a versão pro .NET não tem um copyFromRealm, aqui entra minha dúvida.

Meu metodo deve abrir o realm, consultar o objeto e retornar esse objeto para eu trabalhar fora da camada de dados.

Mesmo usando o DeepCloner (nuget), o Realm fica dando uma exception falando que o Realm está fechado, mas está mesmo pois eu estou usando using, como a documentação sugere.

É possível eu fazer uma copia do objeto do Realm, antes de fecha-lo para que eu possa trabalhar os dados na camada de cima. Esses dados vão ser read-only e não vou alterá-los, somente lê-los.

Codigo que o método faz.

```
using(var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config))
{
    var data = realm.All<DadosUsuario>().FirstOrDefault().ShallowCopy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Com ajuda do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629763/7762411) e do usuário @SushiHangover do mesmo, ele escreveu uma [biblioteca](https://sushihangover.github.io/Realm.Json.Extensions/) onde tem um método de extensão chamado NonManagedCopy.

Este método faz a escrita plana do objeto e retorna o mesmo do Realm, não tendo as responsabilidades do mesmo e podendo usar de forma desatachada do Realm.

O trecho do meu código ficou assim:

```
using (var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config))
{
    return realm.All<DadosUsuario>().FirstOrDefault().NonManagedCopy<DadosUsuario>();
}
```